# Как удалить по индексу элемент с массива и перезаписать гетер со стора?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как удалить по индексу элемент с массива и перезаписать гетер со стора. index - я получаю индекс с массива элемента который нужно удалить.
Структура данных прикрепил. Мутация "setDomainCart"

```
{ "2": { "domain": "dsdf.com", "type": "register", "regperiod": 1, "price": "14.99", "stepOne": true }, "3": { "domain": "dfsafsefsef.com", "type": "register", "regperiod": 1, "price": "14.99", "stepOne": true } }

 handleClickCartClear(item, index) {
    const newArr = Object.values(this.getDomainCart.domains).splice(index, 1);
    this.store.commit('setDomainCart', { newArr });
  },
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хочу по индексу найти элемент и его удалить, записать в store новый массив без этого элемента

Comment: и что не получается? не срабатывает триггер на перерисовку?

Comment: не получается перезаписать в store

Comment: this.store никогда не видел такого вызова коммита, обычно в начале файла импортируется store и вызывается коммит